# How to start or enable Welcome Page in RAD Studio XE5

Tags: delphi, c++builder

For some reason, Welcome Page does not start when RAD Studio XE5 starts.

I tried as follows: 
* Main menu -> Component, Install Packages, checking "Designe package": **Embarcadero Start Page IDE Package**, but unsuccessful.

Does anyone know how Welcome Page can start again?
Thanks!

Comment: You are lucky. Now there is no chance for RAD Studio to call out to the internet and risk a security vulnerability as has happened in the past. I'd be celebrating if I were in your shoes!

Comment: As David says: the welcome page can be a big nuisance, as it tries to access the internet. If, for instance, a certificate for the Embarcadero websites is not updated properly, it can be a big pain in the behind. You don't really need it.

Comment: Of all I use only Favorites, where I have a bunch of links to projects. I've never had a problem with the Welcome page. I think if you uncheck "Embarcadero Start Page IDE Package", Welcome Page will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

As describer [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Welcome_Page) you should do: **View > Welcome Page**

Comment: My question is about the XE5 version. There is no submenu "Welcome Page".

Comment: SOLVED !!!
Check if exists "$(BDSBIN)\startpageide190.bpl" in registry:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\12.0\Disabled IDE Packages
and delete from there.